# Deactivate toast for an android application

Tags: android, toast

My question is quite simple. Is it possible to inactivate all toasts of an application by setting a preference of something like that. Is there for example a method which does that in the SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, sorry! You could implement this yourself, by tracking a preference and wrapping all your `Toast` references in a test to see if that preference is checked.